# Trying to create dynamically growing tables from three columns across multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a dynamic workbook that keeps tracking of employee training and certifications across multiple sheets. Each sheet represents a different area of training, certification, disclosures, etc. Ideally, when someone is added to the first sheet (employee overview), their first name, last name, and title will be added to every other sheet.

Ex: Sheet 1, Employee Overview

| FN | LN | Job | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A_LN | A_Job | 1 |
| B | B_LN | B_Job | 2 |
| C | C_LN | C_Job | 3 |
| D | D_LN | D_Job | 4 |
| E | E_LN | E_Job | 5 |

Sheet 2, Training Tracker

| FN | LN | Job | Training1 | Training 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A_LN | A_Job |  | X |
| B | B_LN | B_Job | X | X |
| C | C_LN | C_Job |  | X |
| D | D_LN | D_Job |  | X |
| E | E_LN | E_Job | X | X |

Columns for FirstName, LastName, and Job need to appear in every table. From there, I need people to be able to manually add new columns and manually enter training (generally just an X). We also need to be able to sort by first name or last name or job (i.e., which accountants have training 1, which janitors have training 2, etc).

Pivot tables don't allow for manual entry in the way that I need it, also this is not calculation based at all. It's all text entries.

I've been able to duplicate/filter the tables on to new sheets - but once I add new columns, the sorting doesn't work right. For example, in a new sheet if I sort by Last Name the X for training1 will stay in the same place, while the LastName column is sorted.

I do not want to have one master sheet that is split into numerous sheets because I think that would be too complicated for a lot of the people who would be using this. In total, I will have approximately 8 different sheets, 50+ employees, and each sheet could have up to 10 or 15 additional columns added on, especially as new versions of training documents and disclosures are created.

I also do not want people to have to manually add FirstName, LastName, Title to each new sheet (mostly because they won't, and things get missed). Although, that's my fall back option if nothing else works. This seems like it should have a simple solution that I just can't seem to put my finger on.

Using Excel for Mac as part of Office 365 to make it. Document will be stored and used in SharePoint.

Comment: Formulas are just going to get messed up. I would consider a macro where you input a name and title, press GO, and it adds that row to all sheets.

Comment: When you say "I need people" are you talking about all those 50+ employees or just 1 or 2 employees performing data entry for the 50+. 50+ employees entering data on an excel sheet is an invitation to disaster, you may be better off building it entirely with sharepoint.

Comment: People would be easily 5-10 staff for this particular spreadsheet. Ideally this would be replicated for different sections of the company (sorry can't be more specific than that), so it could easily be 20-30 people that need to add to it, another 5-10 that would review it for accuracy. All of whom, it's safe to assume, are novices at Excel.